# How to get the option value of selected in Select dropdown

Tags: jquery, select

How to get the option value of a selected in a select dropdown in jquery

```
<select>
       <option value="100">one</option>
       <option value="263">two</option>
       <option value="500">three</option>
       <option value="768">four</option>
</select>
```

Here option value number is random.
 For suppose if i select three, i should get 500.

Comment: This is a very Common query. I am sure that stackoverflow would already have such questions.

Comment: $('selectSelector').val(), what is the question here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery on change event to do this example[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F53gL/1/)

```
$(docuemnt).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){
                 alert($(this).attr('value'));     
     });
});
```

OR

```
    $('select').change(function(){
                 alert($(this).val());     
     });
```

Comment: Nemma uttarakke Dhanyavadagalu koushik. I hope u know kannada.

Answer (score 1):

like this -

```
$(function(){
  $('select').on('change',function(){
     console.log(this.value);
  });
});
```

`.change()` `--->`  http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event to keep track when your `select` value has been changed along with `this.value` to get the selected value:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wHV2u/)**

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var a = this.value();
    alert(a);
});
```